# DateTime is changing when passed to Cloud

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, datetimeoffset

We have a VueJS app that is passing a JSON object back to the WebAPi. The WebApi is sitting on a VM in the cloud.

This JSON object will have a datetime property, along with other properties.

In the WebApi, this datetime is defined in a class (MyClass.cs) as:

```
 public DateTimeOffset MyDate { get; set; }
```

If the value of the passed datetime in my example = "2022-03-15 09:00". I would like to have the WebApi not change the value.

When running the WebApi on my local dev PC, this works when stored to the DB: "MyObject.MyDate.LocalDateTime"

However, when sending the object to the WebApi in the cloud, this adjust the datetime using the offset(-4) and adds 4 hours. The datetime is stored as "2022-03-15 13:00"

My PC and the cloud VM are both on Eastern Time(UTC-4).

Why the difference?

How do I stop the WebApi from changing the DateTime that is passed to it?

Comment: Looks as if it gets stored as UTC, which is generally a good idea. But if the requirement is to store local time, then we need some more context.

Comment: The date is probably not changing.  Just the way the date is being displayed.  Dates are transferred between computers using a UTC value ( a number) and then gets displayed using local settings.  When a client connects to a server the client timezone isn't usually transferred.  So you JSON application which is running on a client webbrowser should b e using the client settings to display the date and not the server settings.

Comment: When in doubt I always set an offset so the time is explicit. The server will honor the offset if you send it like: `2022-03-16T10:05:45-04:00`